# glCopyImageSubData slower than binding & drawing

Tags: opengl

I've read that above GL4.3, to copy one tex to the other, glCopyImageSubData will be the fastest solution,

but after some forloop nested compare, it just not is the case here , glCopyImageSubData is a bunch of FPS slower(~220fps vs ~260fps),

what am I missing can you tell ? is it my hardware ? I'm on GTX 1060 Max-Q ... both testbuf1 & testbuf2 own a TEXTURE_2D buffer and a framebuffer, same size and all

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {

    if (compare) {

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, testbuf2.fb_id);

        glClearColor(0,0,0,0); 

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,testbuf1.tex_id);

        glUseProgram(shader.program);

        vbo.draw();

    }else{

        glCopyImageSubData(
                        
            testbuf1.tex_id, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            testbuf2.tex_id, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            testbuf1.width,testbuf1.height, 1);

    }

 }
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you're measuring the timing correctly? Your bind-and-draw method, in particular, is just adding commands to your drivers command buffer, it's not actually doing any work. Put a glFinish on every iteration to ensure that you're correctly measuring time to do the work.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus hmm ... I understand your point that in my for loop I wasn't unbinding anything, so with this modification, FPS drops to 80 , glcopySub is now way ahead indeed ! Although if I only add glFinish() to both glCopy and bind&draw , result is all the same FPS drops hell down to ~26FPS ....